# Why does one of these 2 promises not update the DOM as expected?

Tags: angularjs, promise

So I'm reading a book on AngularJS and in the section on promises, there are 2 code patterns like below.  They say use the first method, not the latter, but they fail to explain why.  In both cases a resolved promise is to be displayed, but I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

```
<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
```

And the code in a controller:

```
$scope.name = $timeout(function () {
      return "World";
}, 2000);
```

**vs**

```
<h1>Hello, {{getName()}}!</h1>
```

And the following code in a controller:

```
$scope.getName = function () {
      return $timeout(function () {
         return "World";
      }, 2000);
};
```

The Tip from this example is:

*We advise against exposing promises directly on a $scope and relying on the automatic rendering of resolved values. We find this approach is rather confusing, especially taking into account inconsistent behavior for promises returned from a function call.*

I'm new to both promises and angular, and trying to figure out how some of the magic is done.

The book is *Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS* and this is in the 3rd chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the book really show both these patterns? The second one won't work because every time it's called it returns a new (different promise), so angular gets confused and at least in my tests does digest cycles forever.

In either case, both of these patterns aren't good and will not work with angular 1.2.0 and above because templates no longer resolve promises automatically.

The correct way of using promises is really:

```
$timeout(funciton(){
   $scope.name = "World";
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes, it really shows both patterns.  I'd site the page # but I'm reading it in epub so the concept of a "page" depends on the device and font size.  But it is in Chapter 3, right before they introduce $http and $resouce.